# similar file names into array or list

Tags: c#, linq

In each scenario I will have hundreds of .tif files that need to be merged with irfanview. These files are named so that matching character strings before a hyphen indicate they need to be merged (a small example set of file names could be as follows: 0001-1.tif, 0001-2.tif, 0001-3.tif, 0002-1.tif, 0002-2.tif, 0003.tif, 0004-1.tif, 0004-2.tif).  Is there a way to put files with the same "prefix" into their own array by a means of character comparison, or would trimming the file names be easier?  I would like to get all the "0001's" into an array then all the "0002's" etc.  Can someone make a suggestion on the easiest way to do this?

This looks like it will work perfectly, but VS is not recognizing Substring. Is it because I'm trying to insert an array of files into the "GroupBy"? Here's what I have so far:

```
  int i = 0;

        string filmtext = textBox1.Text;
        string[] filmPath = Directory.GetFiles(filmtext);
        string filmfile = Path.GetFileName(filmPath[i].ToString());

        filmfile.GroupBy(s => s.Substring(0,4))
                .Select(g => g.ToList())
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

you could group by the first four characters:

```
filenames.GroupBy(s => s.Substring(0,4))
```

that would return a collection of groups representing the filenames within that group and a `Key` value being the 4 characters that you group on.

To create a list of lists from those grouping you could do:

```
List<List<string>> groups =
    filenames.GroupBy(s => s.Substring(0,4))
             .Select(g => g.ToList())
             .ToList();
```

Comment: That's because `filmfile` is a single string rather than a collection of strings.  Did you mean `filmPath`?